# What is the Difference between Broadcast hash join and Broadcast Nested loop join in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

What is the Difference between Broadcast hash join and Broadcast Nested loop join in Spark?
in Which scenario spark will pick which and which one is faster?

Answer (score 5):

You can get some information from [the source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5089140e2e6a43ffef584b42aed5cd9bc11268b6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L144-L171):

> **Broadcast hash join (BHJ):**
> Only supported for equi-joins, while the join keys do not need to be sortable. Supported for all join types except full outer joins. BHJ
> usually performs faster than the other join algorithms when the
> broadcast side is small. However, broadcasting tables is a
> network-intensive operation and it could cause OOM or perform badly in
> some cases, especially when the build/broadcast side is big.
>
> **Broadcast nested loop join (BNLJ):**
> Supports both equi-joins and non-equi-joins.
> Supports all the join types, but the implementation is optimized for:
> 1) broadcasting the left side in a right outer join;
> 2) broadcasting the right side in a left outer, left semi, left anti or existence join;
> 3) broadcasting either side in an inner-like join.
> For other cases, we need to scan the data multiple times, which can be rather slow.

Comment: How can i avoid Broadcast nested loop join ?

Answer (score 4):

Below are the key differences with Broadcast hash join and Broadcast nested loop join in spark,

- **Broadcast hash join** - A broadcast join copies the small data to the worker nodes which leads to a highly efficient and super-fast join. When we are joining two datasets and one of the datasets is much smaller than the other (e.g when the small dataset can fit into memory), then we should use a Broadcast Hash Join. So it has more efficiently used by developer, when performing left join, right join and inner join. It is something similar like map side join.
- **Broadcast nested loop join** - In nested join for each row of first data set is iterate over every row of other dataset which may degrade performance in join operation.But in certain situation like join keys are not fixed as well as the query is qualified as broadcastable or not, according to the data statistics (size or broadcast hint). If neither of them is evaluated as true and the join type is inner, the query is executed with CartesianProductExec. In this cases BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec is taken. One of the places where nested loop join is used independently on the dataset size is cross join resulting on cartesian product. In this situation each row from the left table is returned together with every row from the right table, if there is no predicate defined. Apache Spark provides a support for such type of queries with org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec physical operator. It's used when neither broadcast hash join nor shuffled hash join nor sort merge join can be used to execute the join statement.

Comment: 2nd point, data broadcasted  or not? implied but then conditional as you state.impression from other answer that it is still broadcasted?

Comment: Yes, the data is broad casted, In Spark SQL, it is handled by the physical operator called BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec that broadcasts appropriate side of the query to all executors and most of time returns a cartesian product.