# How to efficiently compute window functions between dates only at certain points? (SQL or pyspark)

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to compute a window function over the last `x` days, but only need to do this at certain dates. The date at where I want to compute the function is not necessarily a subset of the dates contained in the window.
Also, the above operation is needed to do separatly for different categories of the data.

This is easier to understand with an example (here `x = 7`). There are two tables:

**mydata**

| date | value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-5-1 | 7 | a |
| 2022-5-1 | 11 | b |
| 2022-5-2 | 9 | a |
| 2022-5-2 | 2 | a |
| 2022-5-3 | 42 | b |
| 2022-5-4 | 3 | a |
| 2022-5-6 | 4 | a |
| 2022-5-6 | 15 | b |
| 2022-5-10 | 1 | a |
| 2022-5-10 | 0 | a |

**mypoints**

| date | category |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-5-2 | a |
| 2022-5-3 | a |
| 2022-5-9 | a |
| 2022-5-10 | a |
| 2022-5-1 | b |
| 2022-5-3 | b |
| 2022-5-4 | b |
| 2022-5-12 | b |

My current approach to solve this is with a join:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydata;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mypoints;
CREATE TABLE mydata(
  date TIMESTAMP,
  value FLOAT,
  category CHAR
);
CREATE TABLE mypoints(
  date TIMESTAMP,
  category CHAR
);

insert into mydata VALUES
  ('2022-05-01', 7, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-01', 11, 'b'),
  ('2022-05-02', 9, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-02', 2, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-03', 42, 'b'),
  ('2022-05-04', 3, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-06', 4, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-06', 15, 'b'),
  ('2022-05-10', 1, 'a'),
  ('2022-05-10', 0, 'a');
INSERT INTO mypoints VALUES
  ('2022-05-02', 'a'),
  ('2022-05-03', 'a'),
  ('2022-05-09', 'a'),
  ('2022-05-10', 'a'),
  ('2022-05-01', 'b'),
  ('2022-05-03', 'b'),
  ('2022-05-04', 'b'),
  ('2022-05-12', 'b');
  
SELECT mp.category, mp.date, AVG(md.value)
FROM mypoints AS mp
  JOIN mydata AS md
    ON md.date BETWEEN (mp.date - INTERVAL '7 day') AND (mp.date - INTERVAL '1 day')
    AND mp.category = md.category
GROUP BY mp.date, mp.category
ORDER BY mp.category, mp.date
```

This gives the following output data:

| category | date | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-5-2 | 7 |
| a | 2022-5-3 | 6 |
| a | 2022-5-9 | 4.5 |
| a | 2022-5-10 | 3.5 |
| b | 2022-5-3 | 11 |
| b | 2022-5-4 | 26.5 |
| b | 2022-5-12 | 15 |

My problem is that this method is too slow for my real data, so I wanted to implement this with a window function, but not sure how to do it. Also, I'll end up using pyspark sql interface, so both SQL and pyspark sql dataframe languages are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also looks like it would be faster than the version you proposed above.  This hopefully would be more performant on large data:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
myData = spark.sql("select * from mydata"
 ).select( 
  F.floor(F.rand(1234)*1).alias("category"), #add random column
  F.col("*") 
)
mypoints = spark.sql("select * from mypoints"
 ).select( 
  F.floor(F.rand(1234)*1).alias("category"), #add random column
  F.col("*") 
 )

days = lambda i: i * 86400 #seconds in a day to help convert # of days into seconds for timestamp 

mypoints_extended = mypoints.select(F.col("category"), F.explode( F.sequence(F.date_sub( mypoints.date, -7),F.date_sub( mypoints.date, -1)) ).alias("date") ) #generate the dates to window on to enable join
joined = mypoints_extended.join(myData, ["date","category"] )

windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy(joined.date.astype('Timestamp').cast("long")).rangeBetween( -days(7), -days(1))
joined.select( F.col("*"), F.avg("value").over(windowSpec)).show()
+----------+--------+-----+----+
|      date|category|value| AVG|
+----------+--------+-----+----+
|2022-05-10|       0|  1.0|null|
|2022-05-04|       1|  3.0|null|
|2022-05-04|       1|  3.0|null|
|2022-05-10|       1|  0.0| 3.0| # not as you want trailing 6 days its not always going to generate a value
+----------+--------+-----+----+

joined.select( F.col("*"), F.avg("value").over(windowSpec)).explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Project [date#11596, category#11577L, value#9196, avg(value) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY CAST(CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP) AS BIGINT) ASC NULLS FIRST RANGE BETWEEN -604800 FOLLOWING AND -86400 FOLLOWING)#12054]
+- Window [avg(cast(value#9196 as double)) windowspecdefinition(category#11577L, _w0#12055L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604800, -86400)) AS avg(value) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY CAST(CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP) AS BIGINT) ASC NULLS FIRST RANGE BETWEEN -604800 FOLLOWING AND -86400 FOLLOWING)#12054], [category#11577L], [_w0#12055L ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- *(3) Sort [category#11577L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#12055L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#11577L, 200)
         +- *(2) Project [date#11596, category#11577L, value#9196, cast(cast(date#11596 as timestamp) as bigint) AS _w0#12055L]
            +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [cast(date#11596 as timestamp), category#11577L], [date#9195, category#11073L], Inner, BuildLeft
               :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[1, date, false] as timestamp), input[0, bigint, true]))
               :  +- Generate explode(sequence(date_sub(cast(date#9235 as date), -7), date_sub(cast(date#9235 as date), -1), None, Some(America/Toronto))), [category#11577L], false, [date#11596]
               :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(category#11577L)
               :        +- *(1) Project [FLOOR((rand(1234) * 2.0)) AS category#11577L, date#9235]
               :           +- Scan hive default.mypoints [date#9235], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mypoints`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#9235]
               +- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(date#9195) && isnotnull(category#11073L))
                  +- *(2) Project [FLOOR((rand(1234) * 2.0)) AS category#11073L, date#9195, value#9196]
                     +- Scan hive default.mydata [date#9195, value#9196], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mydata`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#9195, value#9196]
```

Comment: Did this out perform you previous query?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data, you do not provide a method to partition the data.  As you don't have a natural column to `partitionBy` window would pull all the data to one executor and this likely would not perform well. (It does this to ensure all the data is sorted.)

If you had something to partition the data by: my current understanding is if mydata is large and mypoints is small (could fit into map join) this(what you are doing) would run faster than a window.  But if both data sets(mydata, mypoints) are large, then a window would outperform your query.

Here's a slightly faster query under certain circumstances.

```
with expansion as -- subquery syntax
( 
  select 
   date, 
   explode( -- turn array into rows
    sequence( -- Make the date sequnce int an array
     date_sub( date, -7),
     date_sub( date, -1))) as expanded_dates 
  from mypoints) 
select 
 mydata.date, 
 AVG(mydata.value) 
from 
 expansion 
JOIN 
 mydata ON expanded_dates = mydata.date 
GROUP BY 
 mydata.date 
ORDER BY 
 mydata.date
```

This is slightly faster on [small data set on one side of join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554849/what-is-the-difference-between-broadcast-hash-join-and-broadcast-nested-loop-joi) than the above query. (But likely won't beat the above query if both sides of join are large)

```
>>> spark.sql("with expansion as ( select date, explode(sequence( date_sub( date, -7),date_sub( date, -1))) as expanded_dates from mypoints) select mydata.date, AVG(mydata.value) from expansion JOIN mydata ON expanded_dates = mydata.date GROUP BY mydata.date ORDER BY mydata.date").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Sort [date#5288 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(date#5288 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[date#5288], functions=[avg(cast(value#5289 as double))])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(date#5288, 200)
         +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[date#5288], functions=[partial_avg(cast(value#5289 as double))])
            +- *(1) Project [date#5288, value#5289]
               +- *(1) BroadcastHashJoin [cast(expanded_dates#5287 as timestamp)], [date#5288], Inner, BuildLeft
                  :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, date, false] as timestamp)))
                  :  +- Generate explode(sequence(date_sub(cast(date#5286 as date), -7), date_sub(cast(date#5286 as date), -1), None, Some(America/Toronto))), false, [expanded_dates#5287]
                  :     +- Scan hive default.mypoints [date#5286], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mypoints`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#5286]
                  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(date#5288)
                     +- Scan hive default.mydata [date#5288, value#5289], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mydata`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#5288, value#5289]
```

explain of above query:

```
 spark.sql("SELECT mp.date, AVG(md.value) FROM mypoints AS mp JOIN mydata AS md ON md.date BETWEEN date_sub(mp.date,-7) AND date_sub(mp.date,-1) GROUP BY mp.date ORDER BY mp.date").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Sort [date#5273 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(date#5273 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
   +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[date#5273], functions=[avg(cast(value#5275 as double))])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(date#5273, 200)
         +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[date#5273], functions=[partial_avg(cast(value#5275 as double))])
            +- *(2) Project [date#5273, value#5275]
               +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildLeft, Inner, ((date#5274 >= cast(date_sub(cast(date#5273 as date), -7) as timestamp)) && (date#5274 <= cast(date_sub(cast(date#5273 as date), -1) as timestamp)))
                  :- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
                  :  +- Scan hive default.mypoints [date#5273], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mypoints`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#5273]
                  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(date#5274)
                     +- Scan hive default.mydata [date#5274, value#5275], HiveTableRelation `default`.`mydata`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [date#5274, value#5275]
```

Comment: added update with explain to help show why it was faster

Comment: If this is really a large data set, and you needed all the performance you could get you might swap to using unix timestamp, as numbers are smaller than strings and would perform better on large data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt. Both mydata and mypoints are large datasets and have the similar sizes. Also the dates are uniformly distributed.
I indeed have a column to partition the data, but I wanted to simplify the question. Think as if I have a category column on both tables, and the problem is to do the above operation for each category.

Comment: Please fix your sample data and I'll help you write it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the sample data and my query to work with categories.

Comment: I made a new answer arond the same time as your post.